# group by - excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there any way i can group similar rows in Excel?I tried group option in excel 2007 and it did not work for all entries.
I selected the whole column and used group by option.
Example:

name            sub               grade

jill             x                A

mark             y                B

jill             m                  A+

I want this:

name              sub             grade

jill              x               A

jill              m                 A+

mark               y              B

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Highlight the three columns and sort them. I think that the first column selected is the one used for the sort operation.

Comment: thanks so much! no idea why i dint think of it!!! such a simple solution :P :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pivot table to group by the column that provides similarity criteria (the first column, in your example).